# Can a Druid wild shaped into a horse be considered a mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape, mount, mounted-combat

A horse can be pretty expensive to get, and tedious to transport in areas with narrow entrances.
I am wondering if a friendly Druid wild shaped into a horse can be used as a mount, especially since the Mounted Combatant feat gives so many advantages to a mounted warrior.

Comment: Why a *horse* by the way? I mean, why a *simple* horse? There are so many more interesting rideable creatures to shape into...

Comment: Well, in the desert, it's easier to manage a horse with no name.

Comment: Old song references and a dirty answer... this post rules.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## Yes, you can mount your Druid friend

The rules for Mounts indicate that a willing creature at least one size category larger than you, with appropriate anatomy, can serve as a mount. A horse is obviously an acceptable mount, so a Druid Wildshaped into a horse is acceptable, so long as they are willing.

Do note that, because the Druid is intelligent, it must act as an Independent Mount, rather than a Controlled Mount. This means it will retain its position in initiative order and act normally, despite the rider.

Comment: And while this may be a possibility that boosts the rider, it definitely hurts the Druid's action economy.

Comment: Great for long distance travel!

Comment: @NautArch why so? An independent mount can fully utilise the action economy.

Comment: @DaleM Action economy may have been the wrong term. More that if your Druid is a horse, he's not going to do his regular Druid thing very well. You're basically turning a powerful PC into an intelligent draft animal.

Answer (score -4):

Not only do the rules clearly allow for it, it is extremely powerful.

A paladin riding a moon Druid with the right feats and abilities can wreck a monster way above it’s class.  Why?  Because with the Mounted Combat feat you can have advantage on every attack as long as the Druid can make itself bigger than the target.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you give an example.  Welcome to RPGSE.  The [tour] and the [help] offer insight on how this isn't a discussion forum.  Our format calls for supported answers.  You probably need to show how "the druid making itself bigger than the target" fits into the feats and abilities that you allude to.  Also, providing an example of a paladin/druid team versus a monster of a higher CR (provide an example) will hopefully illustrate what you have called out as why this synergy is very powerful.

Comment: Welcome to RPG stack exchange. This is not a place to share casual opinions, we welcome answers which are supported with references to official publications, or well-tested experiences.